# How to send message in code format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I tried something like this but it is not working.

````
async def example(ctx):
     await client.say("```python\n")
     await client.say("print('Hello world!')\n")
     await client.say("```")
````

You can send messages in Discord with code format.

But how can you do it in python with discord API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send *one* continuous message. Like in discord, if you split a code formatted message into three separate messages, it wouldn't render as code:

````
async def example(ctx):
     await client.say("```python\nprint('Hello world!')\n```")
````

You can also use a multi-line string:

````
async def example(ctx):
     await client.say("""```python
print('Hello world!')
```""")
````

Comment: Aside: for convention, we usually name command extensions clients, `bot`